# can we create list definitions for office 365

Tags: office-365

Can we create a list definition using visual studio as sandbox solution and deploy it to office 365.

same for custom web-part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, however I suggest a List Template instead of a list definition. And Site Columns too, because they are automatically added as a managed property

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. But there is one issue - on the public site the link to the solution library is not displayed/ You can navigate to this library by url `https://[your_domen]/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx`